# Remove everything from string after the second - with a single line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to ensure the language is always extracted from a string, only before the 2nd dash (-)

So

`en-AU-Option-A`

becomes

`en-AU`

Is this possible with a single line of Javascript?

Comment: One way is with `split`, `slice`, and `join`. Another is a regular expression.

Comment: A "single line of JavaScript" is ambiguous: a whole library of functions can be written  without line-breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split takes a second argument to specify no. of element desired. so in this case you can specify 2 and it will split upto 2nd `-` and than join `-`

```js
let str = `en-AU-Option-A`

console.log(str.split('-',2).join('-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. This is not using regex.

```js
let mystr = 'en-AU-Option-A'

console.log(mystr.split('-').slice(0, 2).join('-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex solution

```
var regex = /^([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)\-([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)/g;
var str = 'en-AU-Option-A';

console.log(str.match(regex)) // ["en-AU"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```js
var patt = /[^-]*-[^-]*/ig ;
console.log( patt.exec( 'en-AU-Option-A' )[0] )
```